# blog/index.php/author/ what kind of a URL?

Tags: url, php

as mentioned in the title my WordPress blog has this URL. which is not familiar to me. that not a GET request right? what is that? please help.

Comment: "that not a GET request right?" - any URL you type into the browsers address bar is a GET request. It sounds like you might be confusing URLs and file system paths? These are really two different things. However, if you have a "static" site then the server is perhaps automatically mapping the URL directly to a filesystem path and serving that file directly. However, on most modern (database driven) sites these days that is not the case.

Comment: oh i didn't know that. thank u sir. do you know how to generate this kind of URLs? i have a php webpage and articles in database so if i wanna generate this kind of urls how would i do that? .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is *what kind of URL is this*

The answer is: **It's a valid path.**

A valid URL path can contain any of these characters:

```
a-z A-Z 0-9 . - _ ~ ! $ & ' ( ) * + , ; = : @
```

That means .php can appear anywhere in the path - something we recognise as a php file extension.

If someone makes a GET request (the request type is set by the **client** and can be any type permissible in your OPTIONS) and this is processed as an URL path, it will look in the *blog/index.php/author* directory for any configured default files (like index.html, or index.php).

However, your server might be trained to filter for ~.php~ in the URL and pass the path fragment to an interpreter. This means *index.php* is being called with the path fragment */author*. Your Wordpress configuration might be making internal use of this.

Comment: wow, you have a great knowledge. thank you very much.  can you please tell me that if I want to create that kind of a URL manually for my simple PHP website how could I do that? how to generate blog/index.php/author/  without WordPress?